# autocomplete extender not working

Tags: sql-server, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I tried to find my answer in many sites but I think every thing is correct in my code but still the Auto Complete Extender doesn't work.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="190px" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>

                 <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender
                ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" ServiceMethod="GetNamesList" 
MinimumPrefixLength="1"
CompletionInterval="1000" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" 
TargetControlID="txtName" UseContextKey="True"
 runat="server">

                </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

```
public string[] GetNamesList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    DataSet dtst = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConStr"]);
    string strSql = "SELECT FirstName FROM finex.tbl_SenderInfo WHERE FirstName LIKE '" + prefixText + "%' ";
    SqlCommand sqlComd = new SqlCommand(strSql, sqlCon);
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand = sqlComd;
    sqlAdpt.Fill(dtst);
    string[] cntName = new string[dtst.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow rdr in dtst.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            cntName.SetValue(rdr["FirstName"].ToString(), i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    catch { }

    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
    return cntName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need something like this within your <asp:AutoCompleteExtender> tag with the name of the page that contains your web method:

```
ServicePath="MyFile.aspx"
```

Also try the following at the top of your aspx file:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

And this somewhere within the main contents of your page, say after the opening body tag:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true"
    runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I just cut those lines out of one of my projects that works, some may have already been included by the IDE depending on how you added things, so check if they're there already before adding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you solved my problem.It was not explained in any site.

Comment: Glad it helped. As it solved your problem please consider accepting the answer, if you hover near the top left section of the answer you should see a dim arrow that you can click on to accept.